# использование st_contains

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица с объектами, у них есть координаты position_x и position_y. Нужно узнать, какие из этих записей попадают в многоугольник. Пытаюсь так

```
SELECT * FROM `flats` WHERE ST_contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((54.1 26, 54.1 29, 54.3 29, 54.3 26, 54.1 26))'),ST_GeomFromText('POINT((position_x,position_y))'))
```

ничего не возвращает, хотя объекты есть, проверял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы получить точку из координат в таблице не нужно пребразовывать строки, функция [Point()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point) просто принимает аргументы

```
SELECT * FROM `flats` 
WHERE ST_contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(54.1 26, 54.1 29, 54.3 29, 54.3 26, 54.1 26)'), Point(position_x, position_y))
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно. Сам думал, что ошибка в формировании точки, но что-то не нашел нигде нормального примера